# Finding process with heavy disk I/O on FreeBSD

Tags: io, operating-system, freebsd

I wonder how I can monitor which process takes out all my I/O bandwith. The only command I know is `gstat` but it shows cumulative info. Are there any tools I can use to inspect the running processes for their I/O usage? The system is FreeBSD 8.3.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/169676/howto-check-disk-i-o-utilisation-per-process

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功 that's a linux question. However this is more suitable: https://serverfault.com/questions/460634/identify-which-process-is-responsible-for-heavy-disk-i-o-under-freebsd

Comment: @eis sure just saying it is related ;-) 99 percent of googlers will fall here for Linux however :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[iotop](http://guichaz.free.fr/iotop/) is what you want. Most of linux distribution have a package for it.

Comment: But FreeBSD doesn't (at least not in ports). I think `iotop` uses Linux's /proc, which is *not* the same on FreeBSD.

Comment: I wonder why is this upvoted so much and accepted, when the tool doesn't even exist on freebsd?

Comment: THIS ANSWER DOES NOT WORK ON FREEBSD! Check out working answers below or use `top -m io -o total`

Answer (score 16):

The answer is to use `top` then hit <kbd>m</kbd> to display IO percentage per process/thread.

Comment: What version of 'top' is this in? On mine 'm' toggles the memory usage summary.

Comment: @DanielKitachewsky - Works on my FreeBSD: `$ top -v` gives `top: version 3.5beta12`. FreeBSD *does* use a different top than most Linux distrubitions. On my Linux boxes, 'm' toggles memory usage like you mentioned.

Comment: Try `shift+m` to short by memory percentage. `shift+p` for cpu and `shift+t` for time

Answer (score 3):

You can use ktrace if you want to trace a single process:

```
$ ktrace -ti -p PID
```

Do read the [manual for ktrace](http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?section=1&topic=ktrace) so you know how to disable ktrace before using. Something like:

```
$ ktrace -p PID -f debug.txt  
$ ktrace -C
$ kdump -f debug.txt
```

kdump, since the output isn't human readable.

Comment: Yes i know about ktrace but it does not display the weight of each request.

Comment: Wait, the weight? So how about some packet sniffing programs like WireShark or Fiddler?

Comment: No, there is no problem with network. The weight i mean % of disk channel bandwith

Comment: Did you try to use vmstat and iostat to check the timeframe and disk I/O rate? `systat -iostat` `iostat -x 2` `vmstat`

Answer (score 0):

According to a quick research, for Network analysis: you can either use `lsof -i` or `sockstat` (http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sockstat&sektion=1) to identify the sockets opened by specific processes, then you can use `tcpdump` to check the details of that connection (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/08/tcpdump-command-examples/#more-5676). You can also try `trafshow` and `iftop`.

For Disk I/O: on Linux I use `sar -q`, there must be something similar.

Comment: I have no problem with network, only with high I/O of disk (as seen from gstat)

Comment: My bad, I saw "bandwidth" in your question and got confused. Here's an interesting article: http://www.bsdnewsletter.com/bsda-book/Monitor_disk_input--output.html, hope it helps.

Comment: Did you check this other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965821/freebsd-iostat-how-to-tell-if-theres-a-problem?rq=1